# cannot resolve method Sum

Tags: c#, linq

Tried to reuse `Sum` but got this error:

> cannot resolve method Sum

how can I change my syntax

```
   private static void AggregatesData(User user)
        {
            user.TotalActiveUsers = SumToolbarsData(user.bars,(tb => tb.ActiveUsers));

            user.TotalInstalls = SumToolbarsData(user.bars, (tb => tb.Installs));

            user.TotalBalance = SumToolbarsData(user.bars, (tb => tb.Balance));
        }

        private static T SumToolbarsData<T>(List<Bar> bars, Func<Bar, T> selector)
        {
            return bars.Sum<T>(selector);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ does not provide, out of the box, a generic version of `Sum`, for the reason that the language and runtime (prior to `dynamic`) does not **allow** generic (`<T>`) values to be added; there is no `INumber` interface, and the language does not support operators (`+`) on generic types (`<T>`). Either switch to overloads that take `Func<T, float>`, `Func<T, int>`, etc - or use the [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library which **does** include a generic `Sum<T>` implementation, specifically:

```
public static TSource Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
public static TValue Sum<TSource, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                        Func<TSource,TValue> selector);
```

which it does by resolving the `+` operator, and using some smoke and mirrors (so that it isn't slow, etc).